# Data sent from Arduino to Raspberry pi (Usb - Serial) - Parse it into json file

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, arduino-uno

I am sending data from arduino uno to raspberry pi using a usb cable.
The data is collected through sensor on the arduino uno.

I want to write these data on a json file to get ready to send it to a NOSQL database.

Could you please help me , how I can do  ? Script or something like that to parse the data.
I already tried a python script that works to read the data from the arduino.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
while 1 :
    ser.readline()
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data you're reading?

Comment: yes i'm providing formated data when sending .
X ; X ; X ; X ;
I read it with no problem from the raspberry pi on the "/dev/ttyACM0"